# Problems with Azure application manifest trying to authenticate with office-js-helpers in an Outlook web add-in

Tags: azure-active-directory, office-js, outlook-web-addins, office-js-helpers

I'm using [office-js-helpers](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-helpers) in order to get an OAuth token in my Outlook web add-in so I can use it for OAuthCredentials with the EWS Managed API (code for that is in an Azure App Service using the ASP.NET Web API).

I have configured my app's application registration in my test Office 365 tenant (e.g. mytenant.onmicrosoft.com, which is NOT the same Azure subscription hosting the web app - if that matters) as a Native app with oauth2AllowImplicitFlow set to true.  I used a Native app type instead of a Web/API app to bypass an unexpected error indicating my app requires admin consent - even though no application permissions were requested - but that's another story (perhaps I must use Native anyway - not 100% sure).

I made sure that the Redirect URI (aka reply URL) in the app registration points to the same page as the Outlook add-in (e.g. https://mywebapp.azurewebsites.net/MessageRead.html).

Here is my app manifest:

`{
  "appId": "a11aaa11-1a5c-484a-b1d6-86c298e8f250",
  "appRoles": [],
  "availableToOtherTenants": true,
  "displayName": "My App",
  "errorUrl": null,
  "groupMembershipClaims": null,
  "optionalClaims": null,
  "acceptMappedClaims": null,
  "homepage": "https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/MessageRead.html",
  "identifierUris": [],
  "keyCredentials": [],
  "knownClientApplications": [],
  "logoutUrl": null,
  "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": true,
  "oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": false,
  "oauth2Permissions": [],
  "oauth2RequiredPostResponse": false,
  "objectId": "a11aaa11-99a1-4044-a950-937b484deb8e",
  "passwordCredentials": [],
  "publicClient": true,
  "supportsConvergence": null,
  "replyUrls": [
    "https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/MessageRead.html"
  ],
  "requiredResourceAccess": [
    {
      "resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
      "resourceAccess": [
        {
          "id": "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d",
          "type": "Scope"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "resourceAppId": "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
      "resourceAccess": [
        {
          "id": "311a71cc-e848-46a1-bdf8-97ff7156d8e6",
          "type": "Scope"
        },
        {
          "id": "a42657d6-7f20-40e3-b6f0-cee03008a62a",
          "type": "Scope"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "resourceAppId": "00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000",
      "resourceAccess": [
        {
          "id": "2e83d72d-8895-4b66-9eea-abb43449ab8b",
          "type": "Scope"
        },
        {
          "id": "ab4f2b77-0b06-4fc1-a9de-02113fc2ab7c",
          "type": "Scope"
        },
        {
          "id": "5eb43c10-865a-4259-960a-83946678f8dd",
          "type": "Scope"
        },
        {
          "id": "3b5f3d61-589b-4a3c-a359-5dd4b5ee5bd5",
          "type": "Scope"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "samlMetadataUrl": null
}`

I also made sure to add the authority URLs to my add-in's manifest:

```
<AppDomains>
 <AppDomain>https://login.windows.net</AppDomain>
 <AppDomain>https://login.microsoftonline.com</AppDomain>
</AppDomains>
```

This is the code I'm using in the add-in for the authentication with office-js-helpers:

```
    // The Office initialize function must be run each time a new page is loaded.
Office.initialize = function(reason) {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Determine if we are running inside of an authentication dialog
        // If so then just terminate the running function

        if (OfficeHelpers.Authenticator.isAuthDialog()) {
            // Adding code here isn't guaranteed to run as we need to close the dialog
            // Currently we have no realistic way of determining when the dialog is completely
            // closed.
            return;
        }

        // Create a new instance of Authenticator
        var authenticator = new OfficeHelpers.Authenticator();

        authenticator.endpoints.registerAzureADAuth('a11aaa11-1a5c-484a-b1d6-86c298e8f250', 'mytenant.onmicrosoft.com');

        // Add event handler to the button
        $('#login').click(function () {
            $('#token', window.parent.document).text('Authenticating...');

            authenticator.authenticate('AzureAD', true)
                .then(function (token) {
                    // Consume and store the acess token
                    $('#token', window.parent.document).text(prettify(token));
                    authToken = token.access_token;
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    // Handle the error
                    $('#token', window.parent.document).text(prettify(error));
                });
        });
    });
};
```

Now the code in the add-in can properly sign in the user and ask for the required permissions, but after clicking the Accept button on the application authorization step the following error is returned:

> AADSTS50011: The reply address 'https://mywebapp.azurewebsites.net' does not match the reply addresses configured for the application: 'a11aaa11-1a5c-484a-b1d6-86c298e8f250'. More details: not specified

The error now returns every time I click the Login button (the user is no longer prompted to sign in).  It never did retrieve the token.  The full auth URL is:

https://login.windows.net/mydomain.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=a11aaa11-484a-b1d6-86c298e8f250&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmywebapp.azurewebsites.net&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com&state=982599964&nonce=3994725115

What am I doing wrong? Could the issue actually be because the host name of the web app (the redirect URI) does not match the domain of the Azure AD tenant hosting the app registration?  If so, how can I grant permissions to Exchange Online from my Azure subscription hosting the web app which does not have Office 365 or Exchange Online?  Would I have to add an Azure subscription to my test Office 365 tenant so that it can also host a web application??

Answer (score 2):

From your app manifest, I found that you used `https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/MessageRead.html` as one of the `replyUrls`. 
And below is the url that you are using to get consent from user.

https://login.windows.net/mydomain.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=a11aaa11-484a-b1d6-86c298e8f250&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmywebapp.azurewebsites.net&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com&state=982599964&nonce=3994725115.

If you observe above url, you mentioned `redirect_uri` as `https://myapp.azurewebsites.net`. But redirect_uri should match with at least one of the `replyUrls` you mentioned in the app manifest.

Try to replace `https://myapp.azurewebsites.net` with `https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/MessageRead.html` in authorization url.

I have updated them in below url, if you want you can directly try below url.

https://login.windows.net/mydomain.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=a11aaa11-484a-b1d6-86c298e8f250&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmywebapp.azurewebsites.net%2FMessageRead.html&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com&state=982599964&nonce=3994725115

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the URL - that's handled internally by office-js-helpers. I just noticed that URL was in the error returned from the auth dialog deeper in the exception trace

Comment: Could you please update the replyUrl value to  https://myapp.azurewebsite.net in your app manifest and check?

Comment: If I use that URL (without /MessageRead.html) the popup authenticator opens to a blank page as I don't have a root page

Comment: I have gone through the  documentation of office js helper and found that, root url of website will be taken as redirect url automatically.  Can you map your root url of website to some html file and where you can include authentication functionality

Comment: I tried - same error. Perhaps I need to reset the auth process to the point where the user is prompted to login again, but I can't figure out how to do that. Clicking the login button does open the authorization page (not from my web server) but it shows the same error as in my post. I will try contacting the office-js-helpers team on their GitHub repo